# how to catch NaN in presto?

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I tried the following

IF(X IS NULL,0,X) --does not catch NaN

IF(X IS NaN,0,X)  --mismatched input 'nan''

IF(X = NaN,0,X)   --Column 'nan' cannot be resolved

IF(X = 'NaN',0,X) --'=' cannot be applied to double, varchar(3)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`is_nan()`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/math.html?highlight=is_nan#is_nan) to test whether a value is NaN:

```
SELECT if(is_nan(x), 0, x) 
FROM (VALUES nan()) t(x)
```